# Countable collection of dense, open sets

Tags: real-analysis

Edit: The sets in this question will be subsets of the real line. The typical Euclidean metric is used.

In my real analysis book, a theorem is stated: "If $\{G_1, G_2, G_3,\ldots\}$ is a countable collection of dense, open sets, then the intersection $\cap^{\infty}_{n=1}G_n$ is not empty." I have a feeling that there is a missing assumption in this theorem like perhaps they must be nested or something else. Otherwise, one could consider the countable collection of open balls around each integer with radius $1/4$, which should have an empty intersection.

My question is what other assumptions should be in this theorem? Or am I simply mistaken in my counterexample?

Comment: What kind of space are we working in? Just a standard metric space? Complete metric space? Some topological space?

Comment: Note the requirement that the open sets should be dense in the ambient space.

Comment: But they are not dense

Comment: @DavidBowman The real line with the standard Euclidean metric. It's a real analysis book for beginners, so I will edit my post to make it clear that I'm referring to real open sets.

Comment: This is known as the Baire category theorem and you do indeed need to assume that the space in which you are working is of a particular type. It's certainly true, if you're working in $\mathbb R$. Note also, that your counter-example is *not* a counter-example - each set needs to be dense.

Comment: @MarkMcClure I see the issue with my counterexample. Thanks!

Comment: @MarkMcClure Well, you're right actually. There's no way for the countable intersection here to not be dense, since we're working in $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your counter example does not work because your collection is not made with **dense** sets.

The  subsets does not need to be nested, and you are looking at Baire's theorem.

You can find a proof of this theorem [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem).

Note that this theorem can be reformulate like this:

> If $\{G_i\}$ is a countable collection of closed subset of empty interior, then $\cup_i G_i$ as an empty interior.

---

If like you said you are using this result for subsets of the real line, keep in mind that a dense and open subset of $\mathbb R$ must be $\mathbb R$ itself.

Comment: I think your reformulation misses a "countable". Otherwise I define $G_i=\{i\}$ for all $i\in\mathbb R$. $\{G_i\}$ is clearly a collection of closed subsets of empty interior, but $\bigcup_i G_i=\mathbb R$ which clearly doesn't have an empty interior.

Comment: @celtschk Oh of course, thank you for pointing out, I forgot countable...